# How can get a string value returning null when using GetComponent on another gameObject script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string characterRace;

    public void profile()
    {
        characterRace = GetComponent<GetData>().SelectedRace as string;
        Debug.Log (characterRace);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GetData : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //Attach this script to a Dropdown GameObject
    Dropdown m_Dropdown;
    //This is the string that stores the current selection m_Text of the Dropdown
    public string m_Message;
    //This Text outputs the current selection to the screen
    public Text m_Text;
    //This is the index value of the Dropdown
    public int m_DropdownValue;
    public string SelectedRace;

    void Start()
    {
        //Fetch the DropDown component from the GameObject
        m_Dropdown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Keep the current index of the Dropdown in a variable
        m_DropdownValue = m_Dropdown.value;
        //Change the message to say the name of the current Dropdown selection using the value
        m_Message = m_Dropdown.options[m_DropdownValue].text;
        //Change the onscreen Text to reflect the current Dropdown selection
        m_Text.text = m_Message;
        if (m_DropdownValue != 0) {
            SelectedRace = m_Message;
        } 
        else 
        {
            SelectedRace = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error when i try to get the characterRace value, it returns as null when i call via GetComponent on another GameObject

Comment: check if GetData and Character scripts are on the same game object. `as string` is redundant you can delete it. The only null you can get from that code if from GetComponent<GetData>() when those scripts are not on the same game object

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.